# Raspberry stuck with red light (no green light) after trying to connect with 7inch display and GPIO

Tags: gpio, boot, sd-card, power-supply

I bought a Raspberry 5: I run the first configuration and everything seems to work.  in the past, I had purchased the official 7-inch display for a Raspberry 3: however the display cable (the flexible one) is different for the Raspberry 5 and I decide to buy one so I can connect the display.

After connecting everything via a jumper cable for 5V and one for earth, the screen doesn't seem to work: I disconnect the screen, I try to connect only the Raspberry but this doesn't seem to work either: there is only the steady red light.  I tried changing both power and SD (reinstalling the operating system) but all of this doesn't seem to work either.  could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please describe exactly how you connected `everything via a jumper cable for 5V and one for earth` - i.e. which pins did you connect